# Relationship Between Tangent Function and Derivative

Tags: calculus

Is there a relationship between the trigonometric function tan(x) and the derivative of y with respect to x?  Are they just named similarly by coincidence?

Comment: Well, the slope of that particular line at some point on the function's graph is no less than the trigonometric tangent function of the angle the line forms with the *positive side* of the $\,x$-axis at the point of intersection between both lines...

Comment: @DonAntonio could you provide an intuitive demonstration of that?

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo Draw a line (that can be a tangent line at a point on some function's graph or just a straight line). For simplicity, take the point of intersection of the line with the $\;x\,-$ axis. Now, form a straight triangle with that point as one of the vertices, the line itself as hypotenuse, and draw the two legs, one towards the $\;x\,-$ axis and the other one to the other axis, when you must go to the positive direction of the $\;x\,-$ axis from the intersection point . Well, the angle's tangent is precisely how, in the limit, is the derivative defined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is reminiscent of the triangle definition of tangent $\tan \theta=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$?

The derivative of a function at a point can be interpreted as the slope of the tangent line to that point on the graph of the function. This is distinct from the *function* tangent, which can be geometrically interpreted as the length of a special tangent to a unit *circle* (see below) given a certain angle.

[image]

You could connect them in a roundabout way - if you take the tangent line to a function's graph at a certain point, then extent it to intersect the x-axis, the tangent of the angle it forms with the x-axis (measured counterclockwise from the x-axis) will be the derivative of the function at that point.

Comment: Hmm..would that be why they share the same name then?

Comment: Originally tangents were conceived specifically for circle geometry - theorems about tangents to circles doubtless predate Euclid and Archimedes. It is a relatively modern innovation that the term "tangent" should be extended to the graph of any differentiable function, not just circles. However, the idea is the same: the line "brushes" past the graph at one point.
You might be interested in Descartes' (now obsolete) method for finding the derivative of a function, where he would draw an "osculating circle" which touched the function at just that point and find the tangent to the circle there.